# Unhandled exception: 0x80000001: Not implemented. (VC++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, exception

I am using MS Visual Studio 2005 (C++)..

Could anyone tell me what could cause a runtime exception like so..?

> Unhandled exception at 0x07ed0027 (xxx.dll) in yyy.exe: 0x80000001: Not implemented.

xxx.dll is a dll i am working on and yyy.exe is an exe that is calling that dll.. When the undhandled exception comes up while debugging, it takes me to a function but I can't see anything wrong with the function (it doesn't raise the exception everytime this function is called). Anyway, I checked all the values in the function and they seem ok.. If I click continue instead of break, or press F5 after the break, then it goes on like nothing happened.. Please let me know if I haven't supplied enough information..

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the more familiar 0xC0000005, 0x80000001 is the code of an exception that's being raised. You can look them up in `winnt.h`. In this case, I've found `#define STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION      ((DWORD   )0x80000001L)`

Guard pages are used for stack growth. The first page after the top of the stack is marked as a guard page. When you write to that - typically by pushing more data on the stack - a guard page exception is taken. The OS allocates an extra page or RAM (or perhaps 2 - details left to the OS) and moves the guard page up.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know.. If I understand correctly, something is pushing more data than can fit on the stack..? In my specific case, it seems unlikely, it is breaking on a line where I have void pointer casted to a structure pointer, and then checked like so:

...
if (pToStruct->aStructMember==NULL)
...

I checked the values here and they were okay...

Thanks..

Comment: That's one alternative. Another option is that you touch the guard page because of a bug. For instance, if `pToStruct` points to the stack, but the object on the stack doesn't actually have that type, then offsetof(aStructMember) could be too big and cause a read of an uninitialed guard page. Note that you don't usually see a guard page exception, but normally you start wtih a write not a read.

Comment: So you are saying that maybe the object that void pointer that I typecasted to a structure pointer could be pointing to an object that is not of the said structure and is misreading it? Hmm.... Need to do more investigation..

Comment: I didn't know yet you were casting a `void*`. But yes, misuse of casts is a common bug, and could definitely cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I think exception filters might help you to get more details.

USe [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx) to set the un-handled exception filter and check where exactly exception is getting thrown.

Comment: I tried to use it but I can't seem to get it to work.. I tried SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(NULL); but nothing's changed.. How do I make a function filter?

Comment: You need to write a function and pass the function name ( function pointer ) to SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. The control will come to this function when exception occurs.